# Calling a function in a separate CUDA module from an already running kernel *without* cudaLaunch?

Tags: cuda

On the host, I have a wrapper library which JIT compiles a new module. On the device, I have a daemon kernel with its threads waiting for custom commands (like, run this function) from the wrapper library. Are the functions inside the other module callable from the daemon kernel's threads?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, without host intervention, no.  This may change in the future.

Since you already have a synchronization mechanism between the host and the device for your "daemon" kernel (presumably, to pass your custom commands to it), it seems like the kernel could easily send messages to the host as well.  The host could be polling for those messages and dispatch whatever separate functions you want.

Comment: Thanks @Robert Crovella. But that way I do not have any control on which thread of the daemon kernel (and thus which SM) runs the new code. I realize the HW scheduler (Grid Management Unit + CTA Dispatcher) is there to do all this efficiently and transparently. But I am looking into ways to improve (do better than MPS) fairness (while achieving nearly the same throughput) when two or more applications are sharing the GPU especially when there are large grids.

Comment: I don't agree.  Within a "persistent threads" kernel, it's easy to control which thread takes on a task.  Of course, this is simply insignificant when what we're discussing is a matter of signalling to the host.

Comment: Sorry because I was perhaps unclear about my goal. The "persistent threads" kernel is like a supervisor waiting to run user code instead of running anything useful by itself. That's why the question of mapping new task to one or more of these "persistent threads" bypassing the HW scheduler which would just run new task *alongside* (and not "*in place of*") the "persistent threads", defeating their purpose.